# Какие существуют основные способы версионирования программ?

Tags: версионность

Почти у каждой программы есть номер её версии, например: '1.23', '2.3568', '3.89_32', 'Ubuntu 12.04', 'Linux 3.16.0', 'perl v5.20.2' и т.п.

Отсюда вопрос: какие существуют распространённые способы задания номера версии программ и по какому принципу они задаются (что означают конкретные цифры в названии версии)?

Comment: http://semver.org/

Comment: @Nofate "Рассмотрим формат версий X.Y.Z (мажорная, минорная, патч). Баг-фиксы, не влияющие на API, увеличивают патч-версию, обратно совместимые добавления/изменения API увеличивают минорную версию и обратно несовместимые изменения API увеличивают мажорную версию." т.е. допустим есть метод take_foo, и его решили переименовать в get_foo, правильно ли я понимаю совет от semver.org, что я должен увеличить мажорную версию (так как она ломает обратную совместимость) ради этого?

Answer (score 6):

Самая распространённая схема версионирования:

```
major.minor.maintenance
```

**major** - крупные изменения, либо изменения несовместимые с предыдущей версией;

**minor** - добавление функционала без нарушения совместимости;

**maintenance** - исправления.

Может быть добавлено ещё одно число, обозначающее номер сборки (**build**). Например: `2.0.63.4`

Comment: Бывает ещё третьим числом номер сборки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, хотел добавить в ответ, но вы меня опередили.

Answer (score 5):

Например, в .NET стандартно используется класс [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), содержащий свойства `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` и `Revision`. Переведу кусок официальной документации:

> Номер версии состоит из следующих компонент: мажорный* (старший) номер версии, минорный (младший), номер билда**, и номер ревизии, из которых используется две, три или четыре. Мажорный и минорный номера обязательны, ревизия или ревизия и номер билда могут быть опущены. Значения свойств — неотрицательные целые числа. Номер версии записывается в виде
>
> ```
> major.minor[.build[.revision]]
> ```
>
> (части в квадратных скобках необязательны).
>
> Компоненты должны означать следеующее:
>
> - *Мажорный номер*: Сборки (то есть, файлы библиотек) с одним и тем же именем, но разными мажорными версиями не взаимозаменяемы. Старшая версия может означать полное переписывание кода, без сохранения обратной совместимости.
> - *Минорный номер*: Если имя и мажорный номер версии двух сборок одинаковы, но минорные номера отличаются, это означает существенные изменения с сохранением обратной совместимости. Более высокая минорная версия может означать новый релиз того же продукта или полностью обратно совместимую новую версию того же продукта.
> - *Номер билда*: Одинаковый номер билда означает рекомпиляцию того же самого исходного текста. Различные номера билдов нужны, если повторная компиляция производится для другого процессора, платформы, опций оптимизации, или другим компилятором.
> - Ревизия: Сборки с одинаковым именем, мажорной и минорной версией, но разными ревизиями, должны быть полностью взаимозаменяемыми. Более высокий номер ревизии может быть использован для выпуска версии, закрывающей критическую ошибку безопасности выпущенной раньше версии.
>
> Последовательные выпуски версий сборки, отличающиеся лишь номером билда и/или ревизией, считаются хотфиксами (заменами, закрывающими проблемы) предыдущей версии.

---

*Термины «мажорный» и «минорный» — калька от «major» и «minor», но они, кажется, устоялись.

**Слово «сборка» в мире .NET имеет устоявшееся значение.

Comment: `Слово «сборка» в мире .NET имеет устоявшееся значение` – отличное от «билд»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ага, «сборка» — это английское Assembly, единица дистрибуции (обычно один файл, но может быть и несколько).

Comment: а build вы как переводите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Чёрт, для этого случая Microsoft [тоже использует слово «сборка»](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=build&langID=ru-ru). И для assembly [то же самое](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=build&langID=ru-ru). Поэтому я пишу «build» как «билд», за неимением однозначного перевода. [Тут как со словом «поток», которое и «thread», и «stream».]

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать )

Answer (score 2):

Самая распространенная схема с дробным числом – 1.0.0

В такой схеме обычно первая цифра означает мажорную (major) версию в рамках которой есть поддержка обратной совместимости. Следующая мажорная версия например может не иметь какого то старого функционала и будет не совместима с предыдущей.

Вторая цифра обычно минорная (minor) версия. То есть добавление функционала без нарушения обратной совместимости.

Третья цифра это обычно номер сборки или просто инкремент. В этой версии исправление ошибок или не существенные правки, хотфиксы.

Еще некоторые устоявшиеся правила:

- 0.9 – обычно бета версии
- 1.0 – первый боевой релиз

Детальнее – можно начать например с [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: [semver.org](http://semver.org)