# С какого момента начинается отсчёт версий?

Tags: python, telegram, версионирование, версионность

Например, я хочу создать ПО. Отсчёт версий будет идти от 0.0.0, 0.9.0 или 1.0.0?

Comment: Дорогой друг, вот вам ссылка на неожиданный ресурс:-), найденная мной за примерно минуту. Выберите подходящий вам способ. <https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F>

Comment: С любого номера больше чем 0.0.0

Comment: Да можно и [тупо даты использовать](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#history)

Comment: Кстати, текст в правом нижнем углу этой страницы намекает, что Stack Overflow тоже тупо даты использует

Comment: Пока вы в первой бете - 0.x. Первый релиз - `1.0`. Мажорные версии (2.0, 3.0, 4.0) - новая функциональность с нарушением обратной совместимости. Минорные версии (1.1, 1.2, 1.3) - новая функциональность с сохранением обратной совместимости. Ещё подробнее (1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3) - исправления ошибок.

Comment: Схожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521792

Answer (score 2):

Как напишешь так и будет. Никакого консенсуса тут нет.

Например браузеры уже за сотую версию перевалили…

Ядро линукса 5.19 и Линус сказал что следующая будет 6.0 потому что ему так хочется…

Какие-то инструменты годами живут на версии 0.9.x…

Answer (score 1):

А определённого ответа и не существует. Всё от вас зависит.
Как хотите, так и обозначайте

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Это комментарий, а не ответ. К тому же и не несет ничего нового, что не написано по ссылке в Википедии.

Comment: Каков вопрос - таков ответ. То что Сергей не стал постить ответ со ссылкой на Вики .. его дело.